sum cells based on corresponding values in a data set in excel
Can someone kindly help with the following please, I would like to calculate the sum for each person if it says yes in the columns with the corresponding number



Person
Car
House
Job
Holiday
Sum




1
Yes
No
Yes
No



2
No
Yes
No
No







Item
Assigned Number




Car
3


House
6


Job
5


Holiday
4




Is your query resolved or is it still pending, could refer the answer and share some feedback please?

Try using SUM() or SUMPRODUCT()


• Formula used in cell F2
=SUM((B2:E2="Yes")*(B$1:E$1=Itemtbl[Item])*Itemtbl[Assigned Number])


The above formula needs to copy down! Also consider using Structured References aka Tables for the Item Range Data, like I did, I have named it as Itemtbl. This makes easier to work, and formulas also gets quickly updated when there is new row added.

If you have access to LAMBDA() can use BYROW() which spills the formula for the whole range therefore you dont have to copy down for the other cells:
=BYROW(B2:E3,LAMBDA(α, SUM((α="Yes")*(B1:E1=Itemtbl[Item])*Itemtbl[Assigned Number])))


Another way:
=SUM(XLOOKUP(B$1:E$1,Itemtbl[Item],Itemtbl[Assigned Number])*(B2:E2="Yes"))


